# Firebase functions - multiple js files to organize functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a folder named `functions`, inside there is `index.js`.
On `index.js` I have the main function that accept all http :

```
 exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

Since I have many more functions I need to organize my files, and I want to add another file, say `payments.js`, so that `index.js` **can call functions inside** `payments.js`, or even `onCreate` callbacks will be fired from `payment.js`.

If I just create another `js` file in `functions`, it won't work.

What has to be done to be able to have a single Cloud Function in another *new* `js` file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard nodejs `require` to load code in other files.

**index.js**

```
const otherFunctions = require('./other.js');

exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     otherFunctions.other()
}
```

**other.js**

```
exports.other = function() { ... }
```

I suggest reading the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more information.

Comment: then how do we call firestore inside otherFunctions? in generally it need admin initialize in index.js

Comment: Thank you! This worked with stripe API's and firebase functions

Comment: @NandaZ I think you can just pass in parameters such as functions, admin and e.t.c... to the function an use it as needed.

Comment: @PAGEBUNNII yes you are right